# Avoid repeated requests from same svg icons (disk cache)

Tags: angular, typescript, http, svg, caching

I have a page with different info cards. That cards contains illustrations (one per card) and different icons (SVG) with multiple options (edit, delete, more...). Every one of that cards contains an illustration + icons. But **all icons are the same** for all cards.

What I'm trying to avoid is just to call again and again (one per card) the same icons when doing a fetch (I'm using a `app-svg` custom component to fetch the SVG from my `/assets` folder.)
[image: fetch of the icons,first time]

Besides, would be also interesting what happens when browser uses disk cache (2nd time you go to same url). Can I cache only the icon once? What should be the best strategy to do that? Thanks
[image: fetch from disk cache]

Answer (score 1):

I think Angular Service Workers are a great choice for this and bringing other performance boosts. They provide robust cache info strategies for various types of requests, one of which is assets. [Angular Service Workers Intro](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)

If you don’t want to go the service worker route, I recommend looking into an [Angular `HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) and how you could implement a cache at this point responding to requests without it leaving your app.

Comment: Good answer (beside the typo in the first line, blurring the meaning, we get it as second read). A subsidiary question is: why Angular uses fetch when we do `<img src="foo.svg">`, preventing standard image cache by the browser?